# Coding Issue while registerForRemoteNotificationTypes

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I had a support for push notification "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" in my app which is under a macro "EnablePushNotification". That means only if I enable this macro, then my "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" will be executed.

I have recently submitted my app to Apple Appstores, and they have sent me a warning as below:

"Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.

If you would like to update your binary for this app, you can reject this binary from the Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting your binary will remove your app from the review queue and the review process will start over from the beginning when you resubmit your binary."

My question is that I had not enabled this macro "EnablePushNotification" so "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" will never get executed. Also I had not enabled my appstores provisioning profile for push notification. Even then i got this warning. What might be the issue here? Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should also put under macro following UIApplicationDelegate methods

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
```

Comment: But this shouldn't be an issue, since the "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes" is not been called. So the push delegates will not not come into picture.